# Cinnamon take too long time to start

Tags: cinnamon

Is this normal ?

info t=2016-04-28T09:57:34Z Cinnamon.AppSystem.get_default() started in 51020 ms

info t=2016-04-28T09:57:52Z AppletManager.init() started in 13658 ms

info t=2016-04-28T09:57:52Z Cinnamon took 69321 ms to start